# C# (429) Too Many Requests

Tags: c#, web, error-handling, request, webclient

I've been using the WebClient in C# to get specific data from a webpage. That works well until I do it more than 2 times. If I do it more than more than 2 times it gives me the "(429) Too Many Requests." error. I have looked at other questions regarding this issue, by the way.

Comment: You should include links to the "other questions regarding this issue", as well as possibly the code you are using.

Comment: Something along the chain (firewall, target machine etc) is telling you to *stop doing that so much*

Comment: I found the answer and yeah, you were right. I was requesting it too fast so I paused for 1 second on each request and it works perfectly now.

Comment: Please can you put your code before problem has been solved to see how you call WebClient ? With which function ?

Comment: @schlebe sorry, I don't have the original code anymore :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not a C# problem.  It is response from the web server.  Probably some kind of anti-DOS filter.  Try to make a pause between requests i.e. `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);` before each requests.

Comment: Thank you this worked! Now I just need to find the minimum pause time between requests so I can make it request as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this thread is quite old. but I wanted to share solutions

Maybe you can try polly as interceptor to retry the request.

for the policy handler

```
            serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<IExternalAPI, ExternalAPI>(client =>
        {
            var url= "";
            url = config.GetSection("Config").GetValue<string>("baseUrl");
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                .Accept
                .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }).AddPolicyHandler((provider, request) =>
        {
            return Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
                .RetryAsync(1, async (response, retryCount, context) =>
                {
                    if (response.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                    {
                        // Add delay here
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        Logger.LogInformation("Unauthorized Request Occured, Re-authenticating");
                        await client.Authenticate();
                    }
                    // refresh auth token.
```

Answer (score 0):

This post is old, but I had the same issue downloading images from my webserver.
I found the solution on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272838/who-can-download-this-image-with-c-sharp-webrequest)

```
// THIS LINE IS THE IMPORTANT ONE
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; " +
                "Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; " +
                ".NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; " +
                "InfoPath.2; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0)";
```

I haven't had any issues since.

Comment: To adapt, for my application in NET FRAMEWORK 4.5.1, I used:
request. UserAgent = ".NET Framework Test Client";

Answer (score -1):

I recomend to use this code. it's not freezes GUI (wait for 15 seconds):

```
   DateTime Tthen = DateTime.Now;
   do
   {
        //Your code or nothing...
        Application.DoEvents();
   }
   while (Tthen.AddSeconds(15) > DateTime.Now);
```