# Who can download this image with c# webrequest?

Tags: c#, image, download, webrequest

Image link : http://media.isna.ir/content/1435516708689_Mehdi+Ghasemi+%2818+of+18%29.jpg

And my code is :

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://media.isna.ir/content/1435516708689_Mehdi+Ghasemi+%2818+of+18%29.jpg");

WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();

Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
stream.Close();
```

Error message :

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

But I can see that image in Google Chrome and Firefox.

Of course I can download another image from another website. Why the behavior of this web site goes wrong?

Comment: i get connection timeout for that url.

Comment: have you searched for The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary  , Of course.. But nothing about this problem on this web server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because some servers reject requests that don't specify a user agent. Change your method to pass a user agent and it will work.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://media.isna.ir/content/1435516708689_Mehdi+Ghasemi+%2818+of+18%29.jpg");

// THIS LINE IS THE IMPORTANT ONE
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; " +
                "Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; " +
                ".NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; " +
                "InfoPath.2; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0)";

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
stream.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add headers like this

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://media.isna.ir/content/1435516708689_Mehdi+Ghasemi+%2818+of+18%29.jpg");
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)req;
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0";
            request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
            stream.Close();
```

Comment: When you can not get source with WebRequest, but you can view it in browser, you can click "F12" in browser to see what is the request headers the browser send